# Portable way to wait for process to open file?

Tags: c, linux

Is there a way in Linux, that's reasonably portable (mainly to OSX/BSDs) to wait for a process to open a file?  I know I can use inotify for this, but OSX doesn't support it.  One caveat is that I won't actually know the PID of the process, so it's exec()-ed via /bin/sh like popen, so just monitoring it's /proc//fd directory won't work either.

Answer (score 2):

There are several available libraries or command-line tools suitable for this purpose with backends that span Linux and MacOS.

Consider [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch), or one of its competitors (if we got down to debating individual libraries, this would be in explicitly-off-topic territory).

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a library, but your link tipped me off to kqueue, so perhaps I can just write a monitor using that API and #ifdef to it when I'm not on Linux...

Comment: fswatch needs N different backends because there *isn't* a single efficient, portable approach -- if there were, the tooling for the job would be much simpler.